# Find duplicates and give sum of values in column next to it (UNIX) (with solution -> need faster way)

Tags: sum, duplicates

I am writing a script for bioinformatical use. I have a file with 2 columns, in which column A shows a number and column B a specific string. I need a script that will search the file for the string in column B, IF any duplicates are found the number in column A should all be added up, duplicates should be removed and only one line with column A having the sum and column B the string should remain.

I have written something that does exactly that, but because I am not really a programmer I am sure there is a much faster way. My files contain sometimes 500k lines and my code takes to long for such files. Please have a look at it and see what I could change to speed things up. Also I can't use `uniq` because for this Id have to also use `sort` but the order of the lines have to stay the way they are!

```
13 ABCD
15 BGDA
12 ABCD
10 BGDA
10 KLMN
17 BGDA
```

should become

```
25 ABCD
42 BGDA
10 KLMN
```

This does it but for a file with 500k lines it takes too long:

```
for AASEQUENCE in file.txt;
do

  #see how many lines the file has and save that number in $LN
  LN="$(wc -l $AASEQUENCE | cut -d " " -f 1)"

  for ((i=1;i<=${LN};i++));
  do
    #Create a variable that will have just the string from column B
    #save it in $STRING

    STRING="$(cut -f2 $AASEQUENCE | head -n $i| tail -n 1 | cut -f1)";

    #create $UNIQ: a variable that will have number+string of that          
    #line. This will be used in the ELSE-statement, IF there are no
    #duplicates of the string, it will just be added to the 
    # output file without further processing

    UNIQ="$(head -n $i $AASEQUENCE | tail -n 1)"

    for DUPLICATE in $AASEQUENCE;
    do
      #create variable that will display the number of lines
      #of duplicates. IF its 1 the IF-statement will jump to the ELSE
      #part as there are no duplicates 

      VAR="$(grep -w "${STRING}" $DUPLICATE | wc -l)"

      #Now add up all the numbers from column A that have $STRING in 
      #column B

      TOTALCOUNT="$(grep -w "${STRING}" $DUPLICATE | cut -f1 | awk
      '{SUM += $1} END {print SUM}')"

      #Create a file that the single line can be put into it

      touch MERGED_`basename $AASEQUENCE`

      #The IF-statement checks if the AA occurs more than once
      #If it does a second IF-statement checks if this AA-sequence has
      #already been added.
      #If it hasnt been added, it will be, if not nothing happens.

      ALREADYMATCHED="$(grep -w "${STRING}" MERGED_`basename
      $AASEQUENCE` | wc -l)"

      if [[ "$VAR" > 1 ]];
      then if [[ "$ALREADYMATCHED" != 0 ]]; then paste <(echo
      "$TOTALCOUNT") <(echo "$STRING") --delimiters ' '>>
      MERGED_`basename $AASEQUENCE` ;fi;
      else echo $UNIQ >> MERGED_`basename $AASEQUENCE` ;fi
    done;
  done;
done;
```

P.S: When I have fileA.txt fileB.txt ... and use file* the loop still always stops after the first file. Any suggestions why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe pure awk solution?

```
$ cat > in
13 ABCD
15 BGDA
12 ABCD
10 BGDA
10 KLMN
17 BGDA

$ awk '{dc[$2] += $1} END{for (seq in dc) {print dc[seq], seq}}' in
25 ABCD
42 BGDA
10 KLMN

$
```

Comment: I should have just asked here before writing this (for me) extremly complex script. Thank you! I need to get to know the `awk` command more.

Comment: let me know how fast it is for your 500k lines!

Comment: @Vaxin on a side note - python is nice to play with DNA sequences: http://pythonforbiologists.com/

Comment: Thank you! I will have a look into that. A follow up question, how would I set the field separator to TAB with your code?

Comment: @Vaxin 2 ways - "-F \t " from command line or 'BEGIN{FS='\t'}' added to the code - [as per manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Field-Separators)